# Forcing router to use prod controller for certain routes in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

We're developing a site that has lots of thumbnail images. These are dynamically generated from a route such as `/thumb/{width}/{height}/{resizetype}/{id}/{name}` and cached to a corresponding directory afterwards.

Thing is, we're generating the URLs to the images through `$this->get('router')->generate()`, which always uses the same controller as the request making the call. This has turned out to be a problem because loading all the thumbnails through `app_dev.php` is absolutely killing our development servers.

Can we somehow specify the router to build the routes for the prod environment instead? Or should we just build the URLs manually without using the router component?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just this single route ( or just a handful of routes ) the quickest solution would be setting up an apache RewriteRule / nginx rewrite directive for this url to app.php on your dev server.

Comment: Otherwise yes, but that would prevent us from intentionally calling the route through the dev controller in case of a need for debugging.